# Can I unflag a post?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I've made a flagging decision that I later decided was in error. It would have been nice if, in between me regarding it as in error and it becoming disputed, I could have removed it.

(I'm tagging this feature-request because I don't believe this is currently possible, but I wasn't sure what to search for, so it's possible I've missed something).

Comment: meta.SO: [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Comment: I don't know if this is the appropriate place, but I support the feature request.

Comment: @Thomas: if you haven't already, go upvote the proposal Martin linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, you can now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#281010), both for questions and for answers: click on "flag" (below the already flagged post) and click on the dark blue button "Retract flag" below the list of flagging reasons.